# how to change the etherpad's ace2editor to something else?

Tags: javascript, etherpad

i see that on `./etherpad/src/static/js/pad_editor.js` it's being called
as,

```
  self.ace = new Ace2Editor();
```

can I just include and call some other editor (like codemirror) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consensus on the [mailing list](http://etherpad-dev.googlegroups.com) is that Etherpad and ACE are so tightly interwoven that this is probably hopeless for now.